# data continuously inserted in table

Tags: c#, linq, console-application

I try to send data in table when time exceed over 5 mint data is inserted successfully but data insert multiple times  i want to submit data only one time 
i.e. only one row insert only 1 time

this is what i try

```
  if (timediff.TotalMinutes > 5)
                {
                 DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                    var  u = db.tbl_urgent_contacts;
                    foreach (var a in u)
                    {
                        tbl_OutBox tb = new tbl_OutBox();
                        tb.FromSIM_No = a.SimNo;
                        tb.ToSIM_No = a.SimNo;                                   
                        tb.ToText = "Check abc";
                        tb.Reply = "NA";
                        tb.Response = "NA";
                        tb.RegNo = "NA";
                        tb.Datetd = DateTime.Now;
                        tb.FFID = "NA";
                        tb.UserId = "You";
                        tb.FromText = "Check abc";
                        db.tbl_OutBoxes.InsertOnSubmit(tb);
                        db.SubmitChanges();
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: Your naming is weird. `DataClasses1DataContext` is completely non-descriptive and I doubt `tbl_OutBox` represents an entire table but rather one entity in it.

Comment: Code critiques aside, if you're creating duplicate records within tbl_OutBoxes then we probably need to see the containing code calling this code.

Comment: tbl_OutBox is table @MattiVirkkunen

Comment: @TrevorAsh which code?

Comment: When you say `new tbl_OutBox()` are you creating a new table? I don't think you are.

Comment: yes this is not new table.. table already exist in database @MattiVirkkunen

Comment: I give up[...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38156463/227267)

Comment: i call sim no  from this table `tbl_urgent_contacts` and insert data in this  table `tbl_OutBoxes` @MattiVirkkunen

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen what?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen can i post code of this DataClasses1DataContext class?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify this statement:
  if (timediff.TotalMinutes > 5)
To:
 if (timediff.TotalMinutes == 5)

I hope it will work for you